# A finite abelian group must contain an element which is the l.c.m. of the orders of its elements.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G={g_1,...,g_n}$ be a finite abelian group of order $n$ and let $m =$ l.c.m.$(|g_1|,...,|g_n|)$. Since $G$ is finite (without loss of generality) suppose $g_1\cdots g_n = g_1$. We know $(g_1\cdots g_n)^m=g_1^m=1$. Suppose there were a smaller positive integer $k$ such that $g_1^k=1$.

Can I take steps from here to arrive at a contradiction? If so how?

---

Thanks to @menag my candidate $g_1\cdots g_n$ doesn't work. Anyone have an idea for such an element?

Comment: To answer your sidenote: g_1^k

Comment: @Quang Hoang Thanks! Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{lcm}{lcm}$First prove that if $g \in G$ has order $a b$, with $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, then $g$ is the product of an element of order $a$ and an element of order $b$. Conversely, if $h, k \in G$ have coprime orders $a$ and $b$, then $g = h k$ will have order $a b = \lcm(a, b)$.

So in considering your lcm of the orders, you may consider only elements of prime-power order, as the lcm is not affected. Moreover, for each prime $p$ that divides the order of $G$, you need only consider a single element of greatest order $p^{e}$, again because the lcm is not affected. Now reuse the above.

Answer (score 0):

No. Take $G = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. Then $ord(1) = ord(2) = 3$ and $ord(0) = 1$. We obtain $m = 3$, but $0 + 1 + 2 = 0$.

If $a,b \in G$ with coprime order, then $ord(ab)$ is the least common multiple. This could be a help.

Comment: Good point. That puts me one step back then for a candidate of order $m$

Comment: For every finite group of odd order we have $\prod_{g \in G} g = e$. Still have to think about the even case.

Edit: The even case is also easy. $\prod_{g \in G} g$ has order $2$.

Comment: @menag, not quite, think of the [Klein four-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group).

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to use the [fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group#Primary_decomposition).